# PrestaShop 1.4 - check if product has tag

Tags: php, if-statement, tags, prestashop

I need to know if I can check product tags with a function inside prestashop.

PrestaShop 1.4.4

product-list.tpl:

```
{if ???WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE TO ONLY SHOW FOLLOWING HTML WHEN PRODUCT HAS TAG PECIATKA???}
<a class="product_img_link" href="http://www.peciatky.sk/32-vankusik-pre-printy-t4910.html" title="Vankúšik pre PRINTY T 4910"><img src="http://www.peciatky.sk/100-home/vankusik-pre-printy-t4910.jpg" alt="Vankúšik s čiernou farbou " width="129" height="129"></a>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
{if in_array("peciatka",$product->tags[6])} show this text {/if}
```

The code checks smarty for the current products tags (that are stored inside and array that is inside another array) and shows the text that is inside the if clause.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a module that implements the hook "productListAssign" and in the method hookProductListAssign to do that check and to add the flag. You can't do that only in the template and call a method. The $product variable is not an object, but array.